# check existense between two IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
IEnumerable<String> existedThings = 
        from mdinfo in mdInfoTotal select mdinfo.ItemNo;

IEnumerable<String> thingsToSave = 
        from item in lbXReadSuccess.Items.Cast<ListItem>() select item.Value;
```

Here are two `IEnumerable`.

I want to check whether a `value in existedThings` exist in `thingsToSave`.

O.K. I can do that with 3 line code.

```
bool hasItemNo;
foreach(string itemNo in existedThings)
    hasItemNo= thingsToSave.Contains(itemNo);
```

But, It looks dirty.

I just want to know if there is better solution.

Comment: Don't worry about it, I've seen far worse from supposed native English speakers. You're doing fine!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 int[] id1 = { 44, 26, 92, 30, 71, 38 };
 int[] id2 = { 39, 59, 83, 47, 26, 4, 30 };

 IEnumerable<int> both = id1.Intersect(id2);

 foreach (int id in both)
     Console.WriteLine(id);

 //Console.WriteLine((both.Count() > 0).ToString());
 Console.WriteLine(both.Any().ToString());
```

Look for the [Enumerable.Intersect Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx)

Comment: Use .Any() instead of .Count()>0 to avoid unnecessary iteration.

Answer (score 8):

The upvoted answers propose an algorithm that will have O(n^2) complexity if the IEnumerable wasn't derived from a class that implements ICollection<>.  A Linq query for example.  The Count() extension method then has to iterate *all* elements to count them.  That's not cool.  You only need to check if the result contains *any* elements:

```
 bool hasItemNo = existedThings.Intersect(thingsToSave).Any();
```

The order matters btw, make the enumeration that you expect to have the smallest number of items the argument of Intersect().

Comment: +1 for pointing out the order in which you use the collections.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx) to achieve this:

```
// puts all items that exists in both lists into the inBoth sequence
IEnumerable<string> inBoth = existedThings.Intersect(thingsToSave);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
bool hasItemNo = existedThings.Intersect(thingsToSave).Count() > 0;
```

You can even provide your own comparer if you need to: [Enumerable.Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355408.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

It's dirty and it also won't work!  Your `hasItemNo` would only be `true` if the *last value* in `existedThings` was in `thingsToSave`.

Since you tagged this with "Linq", though, I'm guessing this code will work for you:

```
bool hasItemNo = thingsToSave.Intersect(existedThings).Count() > 0
```

Comment: Good catch on the boolean assignment! +1

Answer (score 2):

You may try [intersecting the two sequences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=VS.100).aspx) and see if the resulting sequence contains any elements

Answer (score 2):

Not absolutely clear on what you really want here but here's a suggestion for retrieving only the strings that exist in the thingstoSave and existedThings.

```
IEnumerable<String> existedThings = 
        from mdinfo in mdInfoTotal select mdinfo.ItemNo;

IEnumerable<String> thingsToSave = 
        from item in lbXReadSuccess.Items.Cast<ListItem>() 
        where existedThings.Contains(item.Value)
        select item.Value;
```